# iTunes constantly claims that I have purchased items on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, software-update

When I connect my iPhone 2020 SE to my PC and open up iTunes and go to "iPhone" section then I see a message about update waiting to be installed.

[image]

When I click "Update" I then see:

[image]

The weird things are that:

1. I haven't actually purchased anything, neither recently nor at all. The only items that appears in my purchase history are 0 USD-installed apps.
2. I clicked *File > Devices > Transfer Purchases from "iPhone (name)"* about 20 times so far and nothing happens.

I mean: Sync happens, iTunes syncs something. But it is not syncing "purchased items" certainly, because each next time I click "Update" again, the whole story also starts again.

What should I do in this situation? How to get rid of (probably false) iTunes' claim about purchase existing on my iPhone that are not added to my Library?

Comment: If you check for an update directly on your iPhone, does it show up?

Comment: Yes, but I have to go to Settings to actually see it. There is no notification about new update ready to be installed. I also have automatic updates enabled, but they never happen even though my iPhone stays in Wi-Fi connection all the time and has very fast and stable access to the Internet. The best example is that I have 14.4.2 installed and 14.5.1 waiting to be installed for I don't know how long, because I was never notified about this update.

Comment: Would require a different question to clarify why you don‘t get upgrade notifications. But can you upgrade on the phone then, without iTunes and the question about the purchases?

Comment: Question edited to reflect only the repeating problem of existing purchases. All stuff about upgrade notifications removed.